# Como faço para recuperar e calcular 2 numeros via POST no Controller no Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, post, request

Sou iniciante na linguagem e estou tentando aprender sozinho, criei um arquivo .blade.php com intuito de preencher dois campos simples e retornar o calculo via submit, depois disso pretendo listar um historico armazenado no banco SQL porém mal sei como recuperar informações do arquivo INDEX !!! Então podem perceber que estou bem perdido xD...e toda ajuda e dica vai ser muito útil no meu caso, ainda mais se eu estiver fazendo da maneira ERRADA !!! Segue abaixo os arquivos:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <div class='section'>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>    
                <div class='col-sm-3'>
                    <form method='POST'>
                        <input type='text' name='elemento1'>
                        <input typle='text' name='elemento2'><br>
                        <a href="calcular"><button type='submit'>Calcular</button></a><br>
                        <input typle='text' id='elemento2'>
                    <form method='POST'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

ROTA:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'admin\DashBoardController@index');

Route::prefix('/')->group(function(){
    Route::post('calcular','admin\DashboardController@calcular');
});
```

CONTROLLER:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('index');
    }
    public function calcular(Request $requisicao){

        return $_POST;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro substitua sua blade da parte do ***section***, por esse código aqui:

```
<div class='section'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>    
            <div class='col-sm-3'>
                <form method='POST' action='/calcular'>
                    <label>valor 1 :</label><input type='text' name='valor1'><br />
                    <label>valor 2 </label><input typle='text' name='valor2'><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" /><br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Toda requsição **POST** que você fizer tem que ter um action ( *um caminho para que você quer que os dados serão recebidos* ). Os valores que você quer pegar terão sempre que estra dentro da tag `form` de preferência os inputs deverão ser nomeados.

Substitua o método **calcular** no seu **DashboardController** por esse trecho de código:

```
public function calcular(Request $requisicao){

        $valor1 = $requisicao->input('valor1');
        $valor2 = $requisicao->input('valor2');

        return response()->json(['valor1 : ' => $valor1, 'valor2' => $valor2]);
    }
```

Usar o **$_POST** não está errado, porém você está usando o ***Laravel*** um framework php, então você consegue abstrair isso usando a classe `Request` através do método da mesma class o `input('valor1')` ( que pega o valor do nome do input setado na sua blade ).

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia amigo, é bem simples trabalhar com laravel, recomendo muito que aprenda o [framework lendo a documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7).

1º- Seu formulário está definido de maneira errada. Essa seria a maneira correta de criar, claro para a sua aplicação.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('calcularNumero')}}">
  <input type='number' name='elemento1'>
  <input type='number' name='elemento2'><br>
  <a href="calcular">
    <button type='submit'>Calcular</button>
   </a><br>
  <input type='text' id='elemento2'>
</form>
```

Lembrando que propriedade **Action** é definido em qual rota irá a sua requisição, onde irá todos as informações que estão em seu formulário.

Recomendo ler esse [documentação](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) sobre a tag form.

---

2º- Coloquei um nome para o seu controller para poder acessar ele de uma melhor forma na view.

```
Route::prefix('/')->group(function(){
    Route::post('calcular','admin\DashboardController@calcular')->name('calcularNumero');
});
```

A propriedade **name** serve para nomear suas rotas para poder acessar ela de forma fácil.

A documentação do laravel fala [melhor sobre as rotas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing).

---

3º- Difinindo a maneira que você consegue pegar os valores que vem do seu formlário.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        return view('index');
    }

    public function calcular(Request $request) //Retirei o $requisição e coloqei $request 
    {
      $numeroUm = $request->input('elemento1');
      $numeroDois = $request->input('elemento2');
      $calq = $numeroUm + $numeroDois;
      return $calq; //ou return response()->json($calq);
    }
}
```

Documentação do laravel que explica melhor [como funciona o Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers), 
e [como funciona as Request/requisições](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests).